# Connection to external MySQL instance using Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have tried the following code:

```
MySQLdb.connect(host='xxx', port=3306, user='yyy')
```

But I get the following error:

```
(2005, "Unknown MySQL server host ...
```

I have tried to remove all firewall restrictions on the external MySQL instance, as a test. I am able to connect to the instance from my developing machine.

I believe this should be possible now that the App Engine supports sockets, or am I wrong?

Comment: Did you follow the steps as per this: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access-control#appaccess. I managed to connect with MySQL Workbench but have not yet tried to connect with GAE hosted app.

Answer (score 0):

I think this connection is not allowed (no external socket support in MySQLdb) :
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/?hl=en#Python_Using_a_local_MySQL_instance_during_development
You have to use localhost/127.0.0.1 or CloudSQL socket (unix_socket='/cloudsql/'):

```
    if (os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE') and
        os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE').startswith('Google App Engine/')):
        db = MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/' + _INSTANCE_NAME, db='guestbook', user='root')
    else:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root')
        # Alternately, connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance using:
        # db = MySQLdb.connect(host='ip-address-of-google-cloud-sql-instance', port=3306, user='root')
```

Comment: I think that you are right. I have rewritten my application in Java, deployed on GAE, and I am now able to connect to the external MySql instance.